# What equipment do I need to starting making wine?

Tags: equipment, wine

What equipment do I need to start making wine at home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very little equipment is required for making wine:

- Primary Fermenter (plastic pail)
- Secondary Fermenter (glass/plastic carboy)
- Airlock for carboy
- Syphon
- Bottle brush
- Carboy brush
- Hydrometer with jar
- Spoon
- Cleaner & Sanitizer

  When you are ready to bottle then you'll need:
- Bottles (approx 30)
- Corks
- Floor Corker (I rent one from the local shop)

I recommend purchasing a starter kit from your local homebrew/wine shop. They're normally really great and good prices.

Comment: Is a wine wand required?

Comment: If you mean a bottling wand, sure! It makes bottling a lot easier and is not expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Another great source where my parents buy most of their stuff is at [midwestsupplies.com](http://www.midwestsupplies.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good resources for making wine at home:

http://mountainhomebrew.com/

http://www.wineworldfdw.com/wine_making.html